# Trying to use script in SSIS to seperate first & last names into multiple columns

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

thank you in advance for your input. I'm not very familiar with the script task in SSIS and please feel free to suggest other methods of trying to accomplish the same thing. I'm trying to seperate out First, Last and occasionally middle initial (that is currently in one column) into three. I found I script that seems to have worked for other people and is relatively simple but when I execute the package I get the following error during the script component step: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".--------    at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

The input is an excel file, the output is an oledb sql table. The script code in it's entirety is here:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
 #endregion


 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
 public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
 {

/// You can remove this method if you don't need to do anything here.
/// </summary>
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is called after all the rows have passed through this  
///
/// You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
/// </summary>
public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */
  }




    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        var names = Row.NAME.Split(' ');

        //if lenght is two, not middle skip the middle name
        if (names.Length == 2)
        {
            Row.FirstName = names[0];
            Row.LastName = names[1];
        }
        else if (names.Length == 3)
        {
            Row.FirstName = names[0];
            Row.MiddleName = names[1];
            Row.LastName = names[2];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use a derived column to extract what you need, or even an UPDATE statement afterwards. Scripts in SSIS are unreliable

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but I had a similar issue to this.

For no good reason I had this error pop up, working backwards I eliminated all the code in the script and then all the input columns and still received the error.

Eventually I copied all my code out, deleted the script task added a new task added my code back in and it worked perfectly.

If this is still an issue for you try that out.